# why is ng-repeat called when a none relative function triggerd?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am reading 'Pro AngularJS', there is a demo on 'sportsStore' which has code like this:

**productListControllers.coffee**

```
angular.module 'sportsStore'
    .controller 'productListCtrl', ($scope, $filter, productListActiveClass) ->
        selectedCategory = null

        $scope.selectCategory = (category) ->
            selectedCategory = category

        $scope.categoryFilterFn = (product) ->
            selectedCategory == null or product.category == selectedCategory
```

**sportsStore.coffee**

```
angular.module('sportsStore')
    .controller 'sportsStoreCtrl', ($scope) ->
        $scope.data =
            products: [
                { name: "Product #1", description: "A product", category: "Category #1", price: 100 },
                { name: "Product #2", description: "A product", category: "Category #1", price: 110 },
                { name: "Product #3", description: "A product", category: "Category #2", price: 210 },
                { name: "Product #4", description: "A product", category: "Category #3", price: 202 }
            ]
```

**app.html**

```
<body ng-controller="sportsStoreCtrl">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SPORTS STORE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default row" ng-controller="productListCtrl">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a ng-click="selectCategory()" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg">Home</a>
            <a ng-repeat='item in data.products | orderBy:"category" | unique:"category"' class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg" ng-click="selectCategory(item)">{{item}}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="well" ng-repeat="item in data.products | filter: categoryFilterFn">
                <h3>
                    <strong>{{item.name}}</strong>
                    <span class="pull-right label label-primary">
                        {{item.price | currency}}
                    </span>
                </h3>
                <span class="lead">{{item.description}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

when user click a category, `selectCategory()` is triggered, but why it will make `ng-repeat="item in data.products | filter: categoryFilterFn"` called? so the products are filtered? I have tried to empty `selectCategory()`'s implementation, the filter will still be called, why?

Comment: That's the principle of **dirty-checking**.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. As an AngularJS beginner this wasn't obvious to me at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS uses dirtychecking. They actually call **every** expression to check if the result is different to rerender the view.
Angular does this in the so called digest loop. They call this loop every time some variables are chached inside of angular or outside and scope.$apply() is called.

**Update**

You can use [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) and [scalyr sly](https://github.com/scalyr/angular) to prevent angular from evaluating every expression.
In smaller Apps you don't need them, but I used them in large Apps with a great performance improvement.

Comment: so `ng-click` will call `$apply` implicitly? and check if the model in $scope has changed? but the model isn't changed (data.products), why would it still call `filter: categoryFilterFn`?

Comment: Yes, any change will trigger a $digest(). You can create an isolate scope to avoid being affected by the parent $scope lifecycle.